# How to get text out of ElementHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

Using PuppeteerSharp, I am trying to get the text of the element.

```
ElementHandle elementHandle = await page.XPathAsync("//html/body/div[1]/section/div/section/h2")[0];
```

Now that I have the element handle, how do I actually get the text from it?  I don't see any obvious methods.  I would have expected TextAsync or something similar, but I don't see it.

Using PuppeteerSharp 5.0.

Comment: There is a [GetPropertyAsync(String)](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.JSHandle.html#PuppeteerSharp_JSHandle_GetPropertyAsync_System_String_) method,
please see [How to read the value of an span element with Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307615/how-to-read-the-value-of-an-span-element-with-puppeteer), [Getting a Selector's value in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899557/getting-a-selectors-value-in-puppeteer).

Comment: @Botan Thanks.  That did the trick.  I did `var foo = await elementHandle.GetPropertyAsync("innerText"); `, and then `foo.ToString()` has what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `EvaluateFunction` passing that `ElementHandle` as an argument

```
var content = await Page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("e => e.textContent", elementHandle);
```

If you have many scenarios like that, you can build an extension method to solve that for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

@Botan, thank you!
I have tried (in VB.NET) and found:

```
(Await elementhandle.GetPropertyAsync("innerText")).ToString
```

result: "JSHandle:foo", but

```
(Await elementhandle.GetPropertyAsync("innerText")).RemoteObject.Value.ToString
```

result: "foo"

Answer (score 1):

If your are after a strongly typed API for use with `Puppeteer Sharp` then you can use [PuppeteerSharp.Dom](https://github.com/ChromiumDotNet/PuppeteerSharp.Dom) which is available on [Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PuppeteerSharp.Dom/).

```cs
// Add using PuppeteerSharp.Dom to access the extension methods

ElementHandle elementHandle = await page.XPathAsync("//html/body/div[1]/section/div/section/h2")[0];
// Create a strongly typed HtmlHeadingElement object
var headingElement = elementHandle.ToDomHandle<HtmlHeadingElement>();
// You'll now have context specific methods relevant to HtmlHeadingElement
//Get TextContent via the async method
var textContext = await headingElement.GetTextContentAsync();
var innerText = await headingElement.GetInnerTextAsync();
```

There's a number of `QuerySelector` extension methods also, so you can avoid the `ToDomHandle` method if you are using a query selector.

```cs
var element = await page.QuerySelectorAsync<HtmlElement>("#myElementId");
```

There are more examples on the `GitHub` page.